# How to find correlation between two trends that have different time values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, jupyter-notebook

I have a table that contains time and two types of wind speed trends. I am interested in finding the correlation between the two wind speed trends. Here is the graph below.

[image]

However, the problem is that the wind speeds were recorded at slightly different times. For example, a datum from wind speed no.1 could be recorded on 1/15/18 10:30am while the closest datum from wind speed no.2 could be recorded on 1/15/18 10:31am. When I try to run a pearson/spearman correlation using Pandas from Jupyter Labs (python), I get an error since they do not have any common times. Is there a way where I can still calculate the correlation between the two trends despite them having different times? If not, what would you recommend to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: You can modify the timeframes as per frequency of the data, lets say you record data every second, so take an average for all the time which occurs between 10:30 to 10:31 for both the speeds and then do correlation. As now you will have common column. If you record data once a minute, you can take a 5 minute average and then do the same

Answer (score 0):

If you believe, there is a lag between the two reading, You may use the argmax to get this lag, below simple example it may help you

```
import numpy, scipy
from scipy.signal import correlate

x = numpy.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0])
y = numpy.array([6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])

sample_size = x.size

x -= x.mean(); x /= x.std()
y -= y.mean(); y /= y.std()

xcorr = correlate(x, y)

dt = numpy.arange(1-sample_size, sample_size)

time_different = dt[xcorr.argmax()]

print(time_different)

>> -2 # this indicates we have shifting two samples
```

It might look the perfect solution, at least discovering the shifting amount will help you to proceed.